# how to hide a input type radio in IE and collect the value?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, input, radio-button

i have a "vue" application working properly in all browsers except internet explorer.
The main error I find in IE is the fact that it does not recognize the value of an input if I hide it and wrap it with an image.
This would be my html

```
      <div class="item-wrapper">
        <form class="item-form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
          <div class="cie-item-image" v-on:click="imageSelected = true">
            <div class="cie-item-column">
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="selectedItem"
                  value="1"
                  v-model="itemFormInfo.selectedItem"
                  @change="onChangeItem($event)"
                />
                <img src="../../assets/1.png" />
              </label>
              <p class="cie-item-subtitle">Pen</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cie-item-column">
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="selectedItem"
                  value="2"
                  v-model="itemFormInfo.selectedItem"
                  @change="onChangeItem($event)"
                />
                <img src="../../assets/2.png" />
              </label>
              <p class="cie-item-subtitle">Pencil</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cie-item-column">
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="selectedItem"
                  value="3"
                  v-model="itemFormInfo.selectedItem"
                  @change="onChangeItem($event)"
                />
                <img src="../../assets/3.png" />
              </label>
              <p class="cie-item-subtitle">Rubber</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and here as the hidden with css

```
.cie-item-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.cie-item-column img {
  display: block; /* removes the spacing underneath the image */
  width: 365px; /* sets the width to the parents width */
  height: 244px; /* set the height to the parents height */
  object-fit: cover; /* prevents image from stretching */
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cie-item-column:hover .cie-item-subtitle:before,
.cie-item-column:focus .cie-item-subtitle:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.cie-item-column:hover img {
  border: 3px solid $secondaryColor;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */
[type="radio"] + img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
[type="radio"]:checked + img {
  outline: 2px solid $secondaryColor;
  opacity: 1;
}

[type="radio"] + img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.sub-title {
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: $tertiaryColor;
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  font-weight: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Here I leave a link in which you can see the correct operation, in which if I select an image is selected and the method onchange returns me the correct data.

https://codepen.io/CharlieJS/pen/QWNJvXz

As I explained before, in all browsers it is working correctly except in IE, in which if I don't show the input and select it directly it doesn't recognize the value when selecting the image (neither returns value nor gives the style of selected)

Why do I get this error only in internet explorer?
What can you do to unify the style criteria and apply something similar in IE?

a greeting and thank you all for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution from @Qtax

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
}
label img{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

with this link

http://jsfiddle.net/VdJ9m/

and it works perfect

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.